# Change the fill color of the container from left to right in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to change the color of a container from say white to red. But I want to do it from left to right that is, from the left of the container the color red starts filling up and expands all the way to the right in some duration. I know animated container will change the color but it seems to change the color of the entire container and not how I want it to
Like the 'Next Episode' of Netflix

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Stack` Widget and use an `AnimatedContainer` in between the background container (grey) and the foreground container (displaying icon & text):

```
class NetflixCustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Duration animationDuration;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final double borderRadius;

  const NetflixCustomButton({
    this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    this.height = 30,
    this.width = 130.0,
    this.borderRadius = 10.0,
  });

  @override
  _NetflixCustomButtonState createState() =>
      _NetflixCustomButtonState();
}

class _NetflixCustomButtonState
    extends State<NetflixCustomButton> {
  double _animatedWidth = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: widget.height,
          width: widget.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              widget.borderRadius,
            ),
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: widget.animationDuration,
          height: widget.height,
          width: _animatedWidth,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              widget.borderRadius,
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        InkWell(
          child: Container(
            height: widget.height,
            width: widget.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                widget.borderRadius,
              ),
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.play_arrow,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Next Episode',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _animatedWidth = widget.width;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```