# Flutter animate a button color change in a non-interpolated way

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

With this post, I'm trying to solve this problem: when a button becomes available, I want to change color with the new color taking over from left to right, as if it were loading in.

Currently and for simplicity's sake, I'm using an AnimatedContainer, with interpolates a linear gradient between the two colors and make the new one fade-in from the previous one. Here's the code:

```
AnimatedContainer(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: canGoNextScreen
                            ? color1
                            : color2,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      ),
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1250),
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: onCanGoPressed,
                        child: Text(
                          "Go to the next screen",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: canGoNextScreen
                                ? Colors.black
                                : Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

So this currently transitions from color1 to color2 for the background, and from black to white for the text.

Is there a way to have the next color take over from left to right ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242455/change-the-fill-color-of-the-container-from-left-to-right-in-flutter

Comment: @Er1 Yes, that was exactly it! I ended up adding an `AnimatedDefaultTextStyle` to apply a translation on the text color and it turns out great. Thanks !